# Counting elements matching pattern before a point in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an element in the DOM `d` in a jQuery object and I'd like to count the number of elements matching `font[color=#ff6600]` before the element. Is there a CSS selector I can use for this?

Comment: A thought: I can get all of the elements using `$('font[color=#ff6600]')`. How can I filter that collection by whether each element appears earlier in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what I was looking for. Will test thoroughly in a bit:

```
$(d).parents().andSelf().prevAll().find('font[color=#ff6600]')
```

Answer (score 0):

.nextAll() maybe?

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: Nah, I'd like to include things other than direct siblings, just as long as they appear later in the DOM.

Comment: (that is, siblings+their descendants, of the element, and also of its ancestors)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the selectors [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) along with [.context](http://api.jquery.com/context/) to meet this specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is imprecise so this is my best guess

```
$(d).prevAll('font[color=#ff6600]').length
```

If you mean to collect all `font[color=]` elements that appear lexically before `d` then you can't do this with a pure selector. you'll need to iterate over a larger matching set

Comment: What can I clarify to make it precise?

Comment: I think this is very close, but I need to search the siblings' descendants, as well as the siblings and descendants of all ancestors of `d`.